# Redirect /{POSTID}/{CATID}/{TITLE} to just /{POSTID}/

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I need help with a rewrite / redirect rule to fix some duplicate content issues on my website.

I have a URL structure that it causing a ton of duplicate content. The same page can be accessed with:

1. /Static1/Static2/Static3/{POSTID}/{CATID}/{TITLE}
2. /Static1/Static2/Static3/{POSTID}/{CATID}/
3. /Static1/Static2/Static3/{POSTID}/

So, there are 3 copies of every page.

I need to redirect #1 & #2 from above to #3, so /Static1/Static2/Static3/{POSTID}/ is the *only* URL that will display the content, and the other 2 will 301 to it.

The post ID's and category ID's are only numbers but they can be a different number of digits ( /1/, /24/, /827/, etc.)

The titles include numbers, letters and dashes ( - )

/Static1/Static2/Static3/ represents the folder structure before the part I need to rewrite - those folder names are always the same, and should also be included in the URL.

Comment: You might also find [canonical URLs](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en) useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really quite simple:

```bsh
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(static1/static2/static3)/(\d+)/(\d+)(/[0-9a-z-]+)?/?$ /$1/$2 [NC,R=302,L]
```

The expression requires that the IDs be used, and makes the title and trailing slash optional.

To make the redirect permanent, change `302` to `301`.

Comment: I have one more rewrite rule I need:

Comment: I'm actually all set now.  I was able to figure it out based on the one you posted.  Thank you for your help!